# The error appears only in Code Sandbox.(It works well in VScode.)

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner coder who just started coding.
My VSCode is OK! But Code Sandbox is not Ok..
where javascript doesn't run in Code Sandbox, so I turned on the translator to ask questions. please understand that the sentences may be awkward.

The purpose of my code project is to display two random color gradations in the browser's background color when you click a button. If you continue to click the button, the color code will change from array to random, allowing you to see a new two-color gradation combination.

1. Project goal
   To achieve the project, first of all, the color codes given to the array are Math.random and Math.floor.  The color code of the array item was got from the array through and stored in the let variable. Then, we created a new function, and when the addEventListener detects the button being pressed, the function is executed, and random colors are generated, and we successfully created two random color code gradation backgrounds by using linear-gradient and back-tick sentence body tag.
2. Problem
   The problem is that when I run Go live extension on my VSCode, it was implemented properly without errors in the console, but it doesn't run at all in the code sandbox.
   The sentence part of linear-gradient appears as Type Error, and if you press the button, an infinite error phrase appears.
   I made it exactly the same as VSCode, but I don't know which one is the problem.
   I made too many variables, so I tried to reduce the variables, and instead of the body tag id, I directly mentioned them as body and changed the sentence several times, but it doesn't work in Code Sandbox.

I don't know what part of the code I wrote is insufficient..

For your information, the problem from Code Sandbox is the following sentence.

**Cannot read properties of null(reading 'style')** (error code : bgColor.style.backgroundColor = `linear-gradient(${randomBgColors}, ${randomBgColorsTwo})`;)

(Do you mean you can't read the style? I've never inserted null, but it's also tilted that null appears. It seems that the error sentence itself is difficult to understand.)

Thank you very much for reading the long text and the poor code.

```js
const button = document.querySelector("button");
const bgColor = document.getElementById("bg-color");

const colors = [
  "#FFFFFF",
  "#FF0000",
  "#800000",
  "#FFFF00",
  "#808000",
  "#00FF00",
  "#008000",
  "#0000FF",
  "#800080"
];


function clickButton() {
  let arrayColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
  let arrayColorTwo = Math.ceil(Math.random() * colors.length);
  let randomBgColors = colors[arrayColor];
  let randomBgColorsTwo = colors[arrayColorTwo];
  bgColor.style.backgroundColor = `linear-gradient(${randomBgColors}, ${randomBgColorsTwo})`;

};

button.addEventListener("click", clickButton);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Random gradient Color</title>
</head>
<body id="bg-color"> 
  <button>Click!</button>
  <script src="random-gradient-color.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where do you declare `bgColor` and `colors`?

Comment: The issue will that `bgColor` doesn't represent a DOM element

Comment: Some codes have been omitted for fear that it may be inconvenient to read if the code is long.

All JavaScript code has been added to the body.
Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: OK, and does your code sandbox contain a HTML element with the id of `bg-color`?

Comment: That's right. The html document has also just been added to the body.
There is an ID of "bg-color" in the body tag of the html document.

Comment: Right OK, if you put a `debugger;` statement just before the error, what value does bgColor have when the error's hit?

Comment: It's because codesandbox does not allow you to edit body. Not even with using `document.body.style.backgroundColor`...

Comment: When you insert debugger; before the error statement, bgColor appears in object format and most values appear null.
Thank you for teaching me how to debugger!

Comment: I see... You can't edit the body in the codesandbox! Thank you so much for your reply!

Comment: I randomly put style="" in the html tag, and I just checked the values ​​of bgColor and bgColors.style.backgroundColor in the console log, and it was empty with "". I think the array random code I made was not properly inserted in the style tag.

In my opinion, the biggest problem seems to be that the style was not created in the html tag.
Thanks to everyone who replied to me, I was able to find out!
Thank you so much for taking an interest in my code problem and helping me figure out the answer myself!